# Functional grouping in DbContext for EF6 using FluentAPI and Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a complex object model that I'm trying to tightly control using FluentAPI.  I'm ending up with large blocks of code that look like this:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(t => t.Category).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(t => t.Description).IsOptional();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(t => t.Name).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(t => t.PricingAnalyst).IsOptional();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(t => t.ProductCode).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(t => t.ReplacedByProductCode).IsOptional();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(t => t.Section).IsOptional();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany<ProductReference>(s => s.References);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany<ProductWeight>(s => s.Weights);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany<ProductDate>(s => s.Dates);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany<ProductNote>(s => s.Notes);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany<Rule>(s => s.Rules);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasOptional<PriceDetail>(s => s.Pricing);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasOptional<ProductCosting>(s => s.Costing);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany<Update>(u => u.Updates);
```

It seemed to me like I could stop typing `modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()` so much if I could do something to the effect of

```
using (modelBuilder.Entity<Product>() p)
{
    p.Property(t => t.PricingAnalyst).IsOptional();
    ...
    p.HasMany<ProductReference>(s => s.References);
}
```

would save me a lot of effort, but I can't work out how to structure the `using` statement correctly.  Is this the right road?  If not, what do I do to shorthand the code and make it more readable?

**Update:**

Based on the provided answer, I've created blocks in my `:DbContext` file that look similar to this:

```
        {
            var rule = modelBuilder.Entity<Rule>();
            rule.HasKey(r => r.ID);
            rule.Property(r => r.Country).IsRequired();
            rule.Property(r => r.Description).IsOptional();
            rule.Property(r => r.ReviewDate).IsOptional();
            rule.Property(r => r.RuleNumber).IsRequired();
            rule.HasMany<Update>(r => r.Updates);
            rule.HasMany<Condition>(r => r.Conditions);
        }
```

I chose to wrap each block in curly braces to contain the scope of the `var` so I didn't have some copy/paste accident elsewhere in the code.  I like the way this works, and it makes my code readable (at least to me, hopefully by others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just want:

```
using (var p = modelBuilder.Entity<Product>())
{
    //...
}
```

However, this will only work if the result of `modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()` implements `IDisposable`. Going through the MSDN info on the subject, it looks like it doesn't. If not, you can probably do fine with:

```
var p = modelBuilder.Entity<Product>();
//...
```